# align-items:center not working in custom CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

For some reason `align-items` doesn't work in my custom CSS. Any advice how I can get around this?

Picture of the issue:

[image: Picture of the issue]

This is the code:

```
.list-view {
    display:flex;
}
.item-image {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

I am guessing that the second part is the issue. `align-items` is in white in my custom CSS in WordPress whereas other properties like `display` are in navy blue, so I am guessing that it can't read this property, but I am not sure why that is.

Comment: Post all of the relevant code in the question

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 0):

A working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beljems/y8s4e03e/), I have added `flex: 1;` to the item-image class.

```css
.list-view {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  /* Safari 7.0+ */
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.item-image {
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
}
```

```html
<div class="list-view">
  <div class="item-image" style="background-color:coral;">RED</div>
  <div class="item-image" style="background-color:lightblue;">BLUE</div>
  <div class="item-image" style="background-color:lightgreen;">Green div with more content.</div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps. :)